# COleDateTime ambigous symbol

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, migrate

I'm migrating a solution from Visual c++ 6.0 to Visual Studio 2013. After solving many issues in the solution I'm stucked at the following error in windows sdk header `afxdisp.h` :

`error C2872: 'COleDateTime': ambiguous symbol`

My project use `COleDateTime` like :

In `Date.h` : `class COleDateTime;`

In `Date.cpp` :

`#include <afxdisp.h>`
`#include <streams.h>`
`#include <Date.h>`

Like I said, the error C2872 is flagged in `afxdisp.h`. 
Do you have any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved ! `#include <afxdisp.h>` statement was present in two `.h` files. I removed the `#include` from one of the headers and it's everything ok now.